# individual log file for scrapy 0.18.*

Tags: python, scrapy

I've upgraded my scrapy to version 0.18.4, but I've found previous script to set individual log file for each spider doesn't work now:

```
 #spider/toy_spider.py
 def __init__(self,name=None,**kwargs):
     LOG_FILE = "log/production_%s.log" % (self.name)
     log.log.defaultObserver = log.log.DefaultObserver()
     log.log.defaultObserver.start()
     log.started = False
     log.start(LOG_FILE)
     super(MySpider, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)
```

It works for scrapy 0.14.4, but not for 0.18.4. When I run 'scrapy crawl toy_spider', it seems be in some infinite loop and the message looks like:

```
2013-10-12 19:14:49-0500 [-] ERROR: 2013-10-12 19:14:49-0500 [-] ERROR: 2013-10-12 19:14:49-0500 [-] ERROR: 2013-10-12 19:14:49-0500 [-] ERROR: 2013-10-12 19:14:49-0500 [-] ERROR: 2013-10-12 19:14:49-0500 [PopAppAnnie4Itune] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

I have to terminate the process manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most likely due the double execution of `log.start()`. Use an extension to hookup the `spider_opened` signal and perform there your logging set up.

Something like:

```
from twisted.python.log import FileLogObserver
from scrapy import signals


class SpiderLog(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        obj = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(obj.setup_logfile, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return obj

    def setup_logfile(self, spider):
        logfile = 'log/production_%s.log' % spider.name
        fl = FileLogObserver(open(logfile, 'w+'))
        fl.start()
```

If your project is called `mybot`, then save this code in the file `mybot/extensions.py`. To enable the extension add this lines to your `settings.py`:

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    'mybot.extensions.SpiderLog': 100,
}
```

But you will get the messages after the spider was opened. If you only use one crawler instance per spider, then you can set the log file as an argument:

```
scrapy crawl myspider --set LOG_FILE=log/production_myspider.log
```

In that way you will get all log messages and don't need the extension.

Comment: Thanks for answering. '--set LOG_FILE=' will do the job for now. Just out of curiosity, how can I get the extension to work?

Comment: Right, I've updated the answer with the related setting to enable the extension.